# AdColony 2.5.3.1 Simulator issues

Tags: ios, adcolony

[image]I just updated to the most recent AdColony framework (2.5.3.1), and have had issues with running on the simulator. Every time I try to display an ad, the app crashes. Looking at the trace, it appears to be something related to Audio for the ad. I've attached a picture below.

In addition, the onAdColonyAdAttemptFinished delegate method is never called, only onAdColonyAdFinishedWithInfo.

Are these known issues?

Comment: I'm not seeing any screenshot.

Comment: @AdColonySupport Thanks, I forgot that. It should be attached now

Comment: Hello Jeff, are you showing IAPP advertisement in your app? if yes, then the call back is correct. Can you specify Xcode and simulator version? Is this crash happening after receiving callback?

Comment: Hit "Enter" early... there is no call to AdColony on the stack you posted in image.  You may want to check SO posts with similar call stack in totally different scenario. https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer/issues/11. As simulator uses Audio from your dev box, you may want to try this scenario from another machine with another instance of Xcode. Hope this helps.